# Вопрос по селекторам Jquery

Tags: jquery

Дело такое, есть список постов в одном диве под id="content"
и есть ячейки, в нём, в content там выводятся в цикле посты из базы данных, див идентифицируется id="post"

Хочется каждым из этих блоков манипулировать интерактивно, то есть например редактирование содержимого прямо из списка, нажали - редактировать и понеслась модерация, вот как селектором выбрать именно этот пост и отправить его какой нибудь идентификатор через аякс запрос что бы изменения были отредактированного текста на апдейт точно тому посту что я обращался. Если суть вопроса не ясна, уточняйте, я постараюсь объяснить.

сложно объяснить

Comment: @Алексей Навальный, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Из Вашего объяснения следует, что на странице есть несколько элементов с одинаковым `id`, что неправильно. Как уже сказал mikemilansky, привязку следует делать по классу.

Со своей стороны добавлю, что `id` поста лучше хранить `data-` атрибутах, а не напрямую как `id` элемента.

Совмещая все это получаем примерно такую структуру:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="post" data-id="1">
        <h3>Пост 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне.</p>
        <a class="edit" href="javascript:;">edit</a>
    </div>
    <div class="post" data-id="2">
        <h3>Пост 2</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне.</p>
        <a class="edit" href="javascript:;">edit</a>
    </div>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

И код для управления постом:

```
$(function() {

    function editPost()
    {
        var post = $(this).closest('.post');
        var postId = post.data('id');

        post.toggleClass('editing');

        // ...

    }

    var posts = $('#content > .post');

    posts.find('a.edit').click(editPost);

});
```

**Демо**: http://jsfiddle.net/J87pN/

Comment: спасибо парни

Answer (score 0):

Наверняка же у ваших постов есть id. Так и при переборе в цикле задавайте сразу id=@model.id (ну или как у вас). Ко всем элементам пишете class = "post". Потом просто

```
$('.post').click(function () {  }
```

Вроде бы так.

Comment: Да вот нет, этот .post в нескольких дивах содержится, был бы он один

Comment: Не совсем понимаю. Вы про то, что как по нужному пройти? Юзайте
$(this).attr('id'). Так вы узнаете айдишник поста по которому кликнули. Ну а дальше в экшн его отдадите или что душе угодно.